# How to get only the content that is enclosed in parentheses of a string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that contains some values ​​in parentheses, and I would like to get only the first content that is within the first parenthesis with regex;

```js
const str = "I (want to get this value), not this (value here)";
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const regex = /(?<=\().*?(?=\))/;
const str = `I (want to get this value), not this (value here)`;
console.log(regex.exec(str)[0]);
```